# Rotating raster before tiling

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tiles, rotate

I have a set of referenced rasters (.tif), which need to be tiled but each of them need to be rotated by a certain degree before that using python (gdal mainly as other routines use it as well). In QGIS, for example, I can achieve the right view by changing map rotation value at the bottom right corner of the screen - it does **exactly** what i want, but does not affect tiling process in any way and can't be done outside of QGIS interface, which is important too.

[image: Initial raster view]

[image: The intended way]

While using North Pole Azimuthal projection (EPSG:102016) I tried to define custom CRS similar to it, but had no sucess as +alpha and +gamma parameters work only with +omerc projections.

Should I use custom wkt-defined CRS-es or, perhaps, in gdal tiling instrument there is some built-in way for rotating an image?

Using azimuthal projection for tiling is kind of weird but it has its purpose.

---

Seems like rotation can be performed by changing affine parameters via gdal.SetGeoTransform. However with formulae provided by @MortenSickel I got following result (1 is raster before changing affines, 2 - after). Btw the order of parameters is different in gdal compared to esri world file and that can lead to errors, but i double-checked that.

[image: update]

Answer (score 0):

What might work is to rotate the raster in QGIS and then export it. That would by far be the easiest.

If the tif file is stored with a tfw world file, you should be able to rotate the raster by editing the tfw file. The format is relatively simple, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file.

I would guess your tfw file looks something like

```
10
0
0
10
12345678
876543
```

Where the lines are (copied from the above mentioned wikipedia page)

```
Line 1: A: x-component of the pixel width (x-scale)
Line 2: D: y-component of the pixel width (y-skew)
Line 3: B: x-component of the pixel height (x-skew)
Line 4: E: y-component of the pixel height (y-scale), typically negative
Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the original image's upper left pixel transformed to the map
Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the original image's upper left pixel transformed to the map
```

So if my math serves me right, to rotate the raster n degrees, you would make your lines

```
cos(n)*A
sin(n)*A
-sin(n)*B
cos(n)*B
12345678
876543
```

If you have the file raster.tif and raster.tfw, rename both of them to e.g. raster_rotate.tif and raster_rotate.tfw and edit the new .tfw-file.

I have edited tfw files a few times, but just to move the raster around or change the resolution, so this is just something I know should be working, but it may be more difficult

If your tif-file is without a .tfw file, the same information is stored as field within the tif-file. To get an editable .tfw-file run

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tfw=yes infile.tif outfile.tif
```

This will create the outfile.tfw. To be able to get any effect of this file, you need to open the outfile.tfw in an image editor that can or will delete the attributes. (I tested it in gimp and exported the file as tif, selected the advanded drop down and unchecked all meta data)